# Is reinforcement learning possible for chatbots?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, chat-bots

The reinforcement learning paradigm has the aim to determine the optimal actions for a robot. A typical example is a maze finding robot, but reinforcement learning can also be used for training a robot to play the pong game. The principle is based on a reward function. If the robot is able to solve a problem, he gets a score from the underlying game engine. The score can be positive, if the robot reaches the end of a maze, or it can be negative, if he is colliding with an obstacle. The principle itself is working quite well, that means for simpler applications it is possible to train a robot to play a game with reinforcement learning.

Chatbots are a different category of artificial intelligence. They are working not with actions but with natural language. Person #1 is opening a dialogue with “Hi, I'm Alice”, while person #2 is responding with “Nice to meet you”. What is missing here is an underlying game which is played. There is no reward available for printing out a certain sentence. In some literature the problem of language grounding was discussed seriously, but with an unclear result. It seems, that a classical game for example pong, and a chatbot conversation doesn't have much in common.

Is it possible to combine Reinforcement Learning with chatbot design? The problem is, that a speech-act should be connected to a reward. That means, a well formulated sentence gets +10 points but a weak sentence gets -10 points. How can this be evaluated?

Comment: Yep, this isnt a direct answer but you should look through these publications. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/lab/microsoft-research-montreal/#!publications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed that the 'rules' of conversations are not as fixed as the rules for games. However, you can make use of  descriptive formalism from Discourse Analysis, called *[adjacency pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_pairs)*. These describe regularities between utterances on a local level, for example greeting/reply, which would match your "Hi, I'm Alice" and "Nice to meet you".

You will need to be able to classify utterances by your chat bot according to a set of possible responses, and then you can see if a valid response is produced for any given utterance. If the user asks a *question*, then a *greeting* will not be a good answer, but a *statement* could be, if it was a response to the question. This is leaving aside the content and focuses merely on the formal characteristics of the utterance.

If you want to know more about the topic, have a look at [Conversation Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_analysis), which is the linguistic field dealing with the subject.

Comment: This makes me think it might be worthwhile to formally explore games with fluid rulesets.  (Games, in general, evolve over time, but I wonder if there are any combinatorial games in which rules emerge from gameplay.)